# Insert multiple row different column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

This is my existing table

[image]

In this table, each user has their own respective data according to their **Status**. Each of the user will surely have Status 1.
Now, there are 3 Status to be stored for every user.
Was trying to make every user to have 3 **Status**, by inserting new row of user copying their **Status** 1 data, such that:

- User Ali currently only have Status 1 and its data, so need insert a new
  row Ali with Status 2 and copy along the data from Status 1, again,
  insert a new row Ali with Status 3 and copy along the data from
  Status 1.
- User John currently only have Status 1 and 2, so need insert a new
  row John with Status 3 and copy along the data from Status 1.
- continue same pattern with other user

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: Can you post some consumable data instead of a picture? I really don't want to type out your data since you already have it. Here is an excellent example of the ideal way of posting data. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Don't have 'data' for every example

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, just edited the confusing data with some values for easier understanding

Answer (score 1):

I would use `CROSS JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS`

```
with data as 
(
  select name, 
        column1,
        column2
  from your_table
  where status = 1
), cross_join_data as
(
  select d1.name, t.status, d1.column1, d1.column2
  from data d1
  cross join
  (
     select 1 status
     union
     select 2 status
     union
     select 3 status
  ) t
  where not exists (
     select 1
     from your_table d2
     where d2.name = d1.name and
           d2.status = t.status
  )
)
select *
from your_table
union all
select *
from cross_join_data
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d53be8e1a504c5c425b4f6af038ca1fa)

Comment: What if they have a Name in the original data that doesn't have a status of 1?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
with cte as (
    select
         [Name], coalesce(max(iif([Status]=1, [Column1], null)), max(iif([Status]=2, [Column1], null)), max(iif([Status]=3, [Column1], null))) col1
         , coalesce(max(iif([Status]=1, [Column2], null)), max(iif([Status]=2, [Column2], null)), max(iif([Status]=3, [Column2], null))) col2
    from
        MyTable
    group by [Name]
)

--insert into MyTable
select
    cte.[Name], nums.n, cte.col1, cte.col2
from
    cte
    cross join (values (1),(2),(3)) nums(n)
    left join MyTable on cte.[Name]=MyTable.[Name] and n=MyTable.[Status]
where
    MyTable.[Status] is null
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if data is not nullable

```
declare @table table (name varchar(10), status int, data int);
insert into @table values 
  ('a', 1, 2)
, ('a', 2, 5)
, ('a', 3, 7)
, ('b', 1, 5) 
, ('b', 2, 6)
, ('c', 1, 3) 

select stats.status as statusStats
     , tn.name as nameTN 
     , t.status as statusData, t.name, t.data 
     , ISNULL(t.data, t1.data) as 'fillInData'
from (values (1),(2),(3)) as stats(status)
cross join (select distinct name from @table) tn 
left join @table t 
  on t.status = stats.status 
 and t.name = tn.name 
join @table t1
  on t1.name = tn.name 
 and t1.status = 1 
 order by tn.name, stats.status
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I would do:

```
CREATE TABLE #existingtable (Name VARCHAR(50), Status INT, Column1 VARCHAR (10), Column2 VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO #existingtable (Name,Status,Column1,Column2) Values('Ali',1,'100','90');
INSERT INTO #existingtable (Name,Status,Column1,Column2) Values('John',1,'20','200');
INSERT INTO #existingtable (Name,Status,Column1,Column2) Values('John',2,'80','90');
INSERT INTO #existingtable (Name,Status,Column1,Column2) Values('Ming',1,'54','345');
INSERT INTO #existingtable (Name,Status,Column1,Column2) Values('Mei',1,'421','123');
INSERT INTO #existingtable (Name,Status,Column1,Column2) Values('Mei',3,'24','344');

SELECT * FROM #existingtable;

WITH CTE (Name,Column1,Column2)
AS 
(   
    SELECT DISTINCT NAME,COLUMN1,COLUMN2
    FROM #existingtable
)
, CTE2 (NAME,Status,Column1,Column2)
AS 
( 
    SELECT NAME,1 AS STATUS,COLUMN1,COLUMN2
    FROM CTE
    UNION
    SELECT NAME,2 AS STATUS,COLUMN1,COLUMN2
    FROM CTE
    UNION
    SELECT NAME,3 AS STATUS,COLUMN1,COLUMN2
    FROM CTE
)

INSERT INTO #existingtable (Name,Status,Column1,Column2)
SELECT C.Name,C.Status,C.Column1,C.Column2 
FROM CTE2 AS C
LEFT JOIN #existingtable AS E
ON C.NAME = E.Name
AND C.Status = E.Status
WHERE E.Status IS NULL

SELECT * FROM #existingtable
ORDER BY Name, status
```

This has 2 edits. Initial edit added a where clause to the CTE
Second edit added the values added by the OP

Comment: If every row is 'data' this works but I doubt that is the situation

Comment: If the data in column1 & column2 is the same for each name, independent of the value in the status column. If the data in column1 & column2 is different based on status, you are correct this would not work.

Comment: I doubt status 2 is always equal to status 1.  "User John currently only have Status 1 and 2, so need insert a new row John with Status 3 and copy along the data from Status 1."

Comment: I agree that could be an issue, however based on the information provided by the OP this might work. In the OP all of the entries have a status of one, some also have a 2 or a 3. In all cases he wanted the data copied from 1.  It would be excellent if the OP clarified the relationship between stats and the 2 data columns.

Comment: Since all users have a status of 1, and all inserted rows will have the column1 and column2 data from the matching status 1 entry this will consistently give a correct result. However there are likely more elegant solutions.

Comment: If row 2 does not match row 1 this fails.  You have not basis to state all rows will match row 1.

Comment: Paparazzi an you be more specific on the failure you see? I don't see it but would like to.

Comment: Dude, try Values('John',2,'Data2','Data2');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163266/discussion-between-gerald-r-spangler-and-paparazzi).

Comment: Apparently I can't access the chat features from work. Thanks for the feedback. My initial edit corrected that, but my original post was incorrect as you pointed out. The second update adds in the OPs provided values and returns the result set as displayed in the OP.